# How can I pair an Apple remote with my Mac mini?

Tags: macos, front-row, apple-remote

I’ve got a Mac mini that I’ve repurposed as a media centre thingy.

I’m using its Apple remote to control it. I’d like that remote to be the only remote that controls it, which I think means I have to pair the remote with the Mac mini.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Apple support page ["Pairing your Apple Remote with your computer"](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1619):

1. Log in on your Mac as an Admin user.
2. Get very close to your Mac (about 3 or 4 inches away).
3. Point the remote at the infrared sensor on the front of your Mac.
4. Press and hold the Menu and Next/Fast-forward buttons simultaneously on the remote for 5 seconds.
5. Your Apple Remote is now paired with your computer. You should see a chain-link style lock appear in the center of your screen for a moment.

Comment: Any idea why this might not work?  I have an Apple TV and a Mac Mini running mountain lion.  I paired one remote with the Apple TV easily, but can't get the other to pair with the Mini?

Answer (score 1):

In `System Preferences` open the `Security` section. At the very bottom you have a button called `Pair...` Follow the instructions to pair your remote.

Comment: That button’s disabled on my machine. (The infrared receiver is enabled though.)

Comment: You probably need to unlock for editing by clicking on the pad lock in the lower left corner.